Approximation algorithm to estimate diameter of points in metric space
Given an arbitrary metric space $M=(X,d)$, is there a $(1+\epsilon)$-approximate algorithm (maybe probabilistic or randomized) that can estimate the diameter of $X$? This algorithm should be faster than the brute force approach of computing all pair-wise distances in $X$ and then finding the largest one amongst them. Can someone please refer me to such a paper? I am not looking for algorithms that only work in the Euclidean space.
